# JAXB processing of XML sequences

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to process some XML files using the JAXB implementation shipped in Java 7. I'm using these versions :

```
501 ~ % xjc -version
xjc 2.2.4
502 ~ %java -version        
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

The problematic decalaration in the XML schema is the following :

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="CategorizeType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="se:FunctionType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="se:LookupValue"/>
                <xsd:element ref="se:Value"/>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element ref="se:Threshold"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="se:Value"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="se:Extension" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="thresholdBelongsTo"
                  type="se:ThresholdBelongsToType" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

As you can see, there are two explicit occurences of se:Value in the Type. However, it doesn't stop the compilation using xjc. And if I have a look in the Java class generated for this type, I can see that it is theoritically possible to retrieve the elements of

```xml
 <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xsd:element ref="se:Threshold"/>
     <xsd:element ref="se:Value"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
```

using the following method :

```java
public List<Object> getThresholdAndValue() {
    if (thresholdAndValue == null) {
        thresholdAndValue = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.thresholdAndValue;
}
```

Unfortunately, if I try to get the elements of the list, i can only retrieve the elements registered as threshold in my xml file, where the CategorizeType instance is defined as follow :

```xml
 <Categorize thresholdsBelongTo="succeeding" fallbackValue="0">
     <LookupValue>
         <ns3:ValueReference>OUI_EEE92</ns3:ValueReference>
     </LookupValue>
     <Value>0.3</Value>
     <Threshold>30.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.4</Value>
     <Threshold>40.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.45</Value>
     <Threshold>45.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.5</Value>
     <Threshold>50.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.55</Value>
     <Threshold>55.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.6</Value>
     <Threshold>60.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.7</Value>
     <Threshold>70.0</Threshold>
     <Value>0.8</Value>
     <Extension>
         <ExtensionParameter name="method">MANUAL</ExtensionParameter>
     </Extension>
 </Categorize>
```

When retrieving the list, I can only see the Threshold values.

Do I make something wrong ? Is it an inner limitation of Jaxb ?

Note that I can't change the XML schema...

EDIT :

I've just run xjc with the -v option, and I obtain globally the same output. With verbosity :

```
xjc -verbose se/2.0/All.xsd
parsing a schema...
[WARNING] java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
  line 23 of file:/home/alexis/crap/SE-Schema-2.0/ows/2.0/ows19115subset.xsd

[WARNING] java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
  line 22 of file:/home/alexis/crap/SE-Schema-2.0/filter/2.0/filterCapabilities.xsd

compiling a schema...
[INFO] generating codee
unknown location
```

Without it :

```
xjc se/2.0/All.xsd 
parsing a schema...
[WARNING] java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
  line 23 of file:/home/alexis/crap/SE-Schema-2.0/ows/2.0/ows19115subset.xsd

[WARNING] java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
  line 22 of file:/home/alexis/crap/SE-Schema-2.0/ows/2.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd

compiling a schema...
```

The following output just contains the name and location of the generated files.

I have forgotten to say that this xsd couldn't be compiled with the xjc shipped with Java 6. Last tried has been made with JAXB 2.1.10.I can't reproduce this behaviour now, as I'm now working with Java 7.

EDIT2 :

I've just tried to customize the binginds, as suggested in comments. My binding file is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jxb:bindings jxb:version="1.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    >
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" 
                   node="//xsd:complexType[@name='CategorizeType']">
        <jxb:bindings 
                  node="xsd:complexContent/xsd:extension/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@ref='se:Value'][position()=1]">
            <jxb:property name="FirstValue"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The first value instance is indeed replaced by a firstValue attribute in the Java code

```
@XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
protected ParameterValueType firstValue;
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "Threshold", type = LiteralType.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", type = ParameterValueType.class)
})
protected List<Object> thresholdAndValue;

public ParameterValueType getFirstValue() {
    return firstValue;
}
public void setFirstValue(ParameterValueType value) {
    this.firstValue = value;
}
public List<Object> getThresholdAndValue() {
    if (thresholdAndValue == null) {
        thresholdAndValue = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.thresholdAndValue;
}
```

Unfortunately, I still obtain the same result - I still can't see my values in the list returned by getThresholdAndValues(). I'm still exploring the customization way...

Comment: What are the annotations on the `getThresholdAndValue` method? That's the interesting part, not the method body.

Comment: None. The only annotations I can find in this class are set on the class and on its attributes. None of them are set on a method...

Comment: Interesting problem - please could you post the full schema?

Comment: PS You could temporarily change the schema just to experiment - it could be a namespaces problem?

Comment: davidfrancis : I can't post the full schema, sry. Btw, it's very long, and dependant on other very long schemas... I've already tried to change it... replacing the first Value instance with a dedicated FirstValueType instance. The type is the same, but the name change. And it works... But I must not change the schema.

Comment: Sounds like you may have found a JAXB bug. Maybe you could debug it when it works (with the name change) and when it doesn't? Another (horrible) suggestion would be to transform the data first to the alternate schema (with the name change) and then process that. Or just don't use JAXB?I do know that JAXB allows some sort of binding customisation - maybe you could google that and see if it helps?

Comment: I feel like you are getting some sort of namespace conflict between two se:value items. Run your compiler with the verbosity turned up.

Comment: @nsfyn55 : Done, I've edited my post.

Comment: I wonder if using binding customizations to map the `Value` elements to two different java classes would help? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp149350

Comment: @JörnHorstmann : I try right now.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann : I've edited to explain what I've made with the bindings, and how it unfortunately didn't work... But as I'm discovering this, I may miss something ;-) Your link was very valuable, though. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Sorry I had to give up on this, I just couldn't get it to work either (it would be so much easier if you could change your schema!). I was using the [Codehaus JAXB maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/index.html). I'm pretty sure it's a conflict caused by the two *Value* elements, which I tried to fix with an xjb customisation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jxb:bindings jxb:version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/example.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.example" />
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

It had absolutely no effect. I tried `<jxb:typeName suffix="Element"/>`, and it renamed all of the JAXB classes, so I assume there's a bug with the `jxb:elementName` feature.

**Original Post:**

I've been looking at this and I'm able to replicate your problem.

I took a few liberties with your schema to simplify things, but it still contains the essential elements. Here is what I've been using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:se="http://com.example/example" 
        targetNamespace="http://com.example/example"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="Categorize" type="se:CategorizeType" />

    <xsd:complexType name="FunctionType">
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="Value">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="Threshold">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="CategorizeType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="se:FunctionType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Value" type="se:Value" />
                    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:element name="Threshold" type="se:Threshold" />
                        <xsd:element name="Value" type="se:Value" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I've removed any elements/attributes not related to the issue, used `name/type` instead of `ref`, and defined the types missing from your provided schema.

My generated JAXB CategorizeType class looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CategorizeType", propOrder = {
    "value",
    "thresholdAndValue"
})
public class CategorizeType
    extends FunctionType
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    protected String value;
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "Value", 
            namespace = "http://com.example/example", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "Threshold", 
            namespace = "http://com.example/example", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<String>> thresholdAndValue;

    ...
}
```

When I unmarshall your XML, my Categorize.Value is `0.8` (instead of the expected `0.3`), and the values of each ThresholdAndValue (all `Strings` in my case) are `30.0, 40.0, 45.0`, etc. The `0.4, 0.45`, etc are missing.

**When I remove the first `Value` element from the schema and then unmarshall, I get all of the expected values, so there's definitely a conflict!**

However, when I marshall using the following JAXB setup:

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
CategorizeType catType = factory.createCategorizeType();
catType.setValue("0.3");
JAXBElement<String> thresh = factory.createCategorizeTypeThreshold("30.0");
JAXBElement<String> threshVal = factory.createCategorizeTypeValue("0.4");
JAXBElement<String> thresh2 = factory.createCategorizeTypeThreshold("40.0");
JAXBElement<String> threshVal2 = factory.createCategorizeTypeValue("0.45");
catType.getThresholdAndValue().add(thresh);
catType.getThresholdAndValue().add(threshVal);
catType.getThresholdAndValue().add(thresh2);
catType.getThresholdAndValue().add(threshVal2);
JAXBElement<CategorizeType> element = factory.createCategorize(catType);
// marshall to XML here!
```

I get the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Categorize xmlns="http://com.example/example">
    <Value>0.3</Value>
    <Threshold>30.0</Threshold>
    <Value>0.4</Value>
    <Threshold>40.0</Threshold>
    <Value>0.45</Value>
</Categorize>
```

I'll keep looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

i think you need a complexType element around

```
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element ref="se:Threshold"/>
                <xsd:element ref="se:Value"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
```

Can you insert an XSLT transformation to add a ComplexType to the schema definition before running xjc?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. As I've never used XSLT before, it will take me some time :-p. I had identified that this list was the key of my problem, and that it would have been much more simple if it had been defined in a separate complex type. But as I'm not used to XSLT, I didn't think to use it. I'll try it, as I'm free to customize the compilation of the XML (even if I can't touch the XML itself).

Comment: What I'm afraid of, though, is that I don't want to have to apply any transformation to the files defined using this XSD. Consequently, I'll have to be able to read a list of threshold of value, whithout any intermediate element...